Implementation of navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() for screen sharing in android webview
I was doing some tests using webview and realized that WebRTC for Android does not implement the navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() function to have access to the system display.
I'm trying to implement navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() in an Android webview using react-native-webview to be able to use screen sharing in video conferencing web apps like Google Meet, Zoom, Teams and Jitsi.
I created a fake navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() to try to circumvent errors when apps try to access this function:
const debugging = `
    sessionStorage.clear()
    function createMockTrack(kind) {
      return {
        kind,
        label: 'Mock  Track',
        enabled: true,
        id:'2',
        readyState: 'live',
        stop: () => console.log(''),
      };
    }
    
    // Create a fake MediaStream
    function createMockMediaStream() {
      return {
        id: 'mock-stream-id',
        active: true,
        getTracks: () => [createMockTrack('video')],
        getVideoTracks: () => [createMockTrack('video')],
        getAudioTracks: () => [],
        addTrack: (track) => console.log(''),
        removeTrack: (track) => console.log(''),
        getTrackById: (id) => createMockTrack('video'),
      };
    }
    
    // Fake getDisplayMedia function
    function fakeGetDisplayMedia(constraints) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Simulate asynchronous behavior
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Fake getDisplayMedia called with constraints:', constraints);
          // Resolve with a mock MediaStream object
          resolve(createMockMediaStream());
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
    
    // Override the original getDisplayMedia function
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia = fakeGetDisplayMedia;
    } else {
      navigator.mediaDevices = {
        getDisplayMedia: fakeGetDisplayMedia,
      };
    }
    
      // const consoleLog = (type, log) => window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'type': 'Console', 'data': {'type': type, 'log': log}}));
      // console = {
      //     log: (log) => consoleLog('log', log),
      //     debug: (log) => consoleLog('debug', log),
      //     info: (log) => consoleLog('info', log),
      //     warn: (log) => consoleLog('warn', log),
      //     error: (log) => consoleLog('error', log),
      //   };
    `;

I added this code to run in the webview before the page loads:
<WebView 
              ref={webRef}
              mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
              
              originWhitelist={['*']}
              source={{ uri: 'https://meet.maiascript.com/' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} 
              webviewDebuggingEnabled={true}
             
              injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={debugging}
              onMessage={(event)=>console.log(event)}
              userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0"

            />

After creating this fake, when I try to access an app based on Jitsi, the share button appears but it gives an error when I try to start sharing because I didn't implement screen projection

Is there any way for Webview to be able to share the system screen?
